# About error lun new not found of server IBM AIX version 7.2

Tags: aix, core-banking

Have error when addtion lun new from disk cabinet Hitachi mapping to server IBM AIX version 7.2 is not found in list of lun with show is "lspv" and scan lun is "cfgmgr". So i sure and decided reboot server at 8 minutes.
Conclude is not found lun new in list of server AIX.
Please advise for me
Thanks so much
[image: is error when run cfgmgris version aix 7.2]

is tried reboot server and failed.
Have partner IBM share advise server for core banking version 7.2

Comment: Asked your hardware-vendor yet?

Comment: Probably better suited at Unix & Linux.